# Segate NTFS hard disk on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I have Segate external hard disk which can hold upto 1 TB data. I was able to use this hard disk on my Mac laptop even after upgrading to Mountain Lion.

However since last 2 weeks I am not able to see the contents of my hard disk on my laptop. The sidebar shows that the disk is attached to the laptop and info option is showing the correct used and free space. Hoever the contents are not visible.

I am also able to copy or create folders on the disk but agaib the newly created things are not visible. In short I can't see anything inside the hard disk. However the contents are visible on other machines like ubuntu.

Could someone advise me on what I should do in order to be able to use my hard disk on my laptop?

Comment: a) This is the wrong place for this question. It should be asked at Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the permissions, and repairing disk in Disk Utility. Macs don't natively run NTFS, did you recently uninstall an app that lets you write to NTFS. Here is a website that shows apps that let you write to NTFS http://appducate.com/2013/01/read-write-to-windows-ntfs-partition-on-mac/